# How to use ngx-Admin components, without using ngx-Admin Starter Kit?

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

I have created a new project in Angular with nebular installed. I don't want to use ngx-Admin Starter kit. But can I use all the components from ngx-Admin Starter kit in my new Project without using the starter kit?

So Is it possible to build 100% UI with an only nebular library which should exactly look like ngx-Admin Starter Kit UI?

For Example : I am not able to use `<ngx-sample-layout></ngx-sample-layout>` in my new project.Simillarly what about other components like (`<ngx-ecommerce-charts></ngx-ecommerce-charts>, <ngx-country-orders></ngx-country-orders>, <ngx-progress-section></ngx-progress-section>` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use components from the ngx-admin starter kit without using the ngx-admin starter kit.

For example, `ngx-sample-layout` is not part of the `@nebular` packages you define in your `package.json`, it is part of ngx-admin.

> So Is it possible to build 100% UI with an only nebular library which should exactly look like ngx-Admin Starter Kit UI?

This is literally what ngx-admin is (it creates a UI using Nebular elements). If you want to do exactly that, simply copy what ngx-admin does.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guide on this page. This will give you all the styles you need from Nebular without having the starter kit code.

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/install-nebular#manually